# Searching Only From td table not from Header (th)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I can search from the entire table by using jquery and show only tr that match from search and it make header (th) gone. But i want it only search from table content. (Header stay and content that match show)

> here my style

```
<style>
  td{border: 1px solid black}
</style>
```

> here my html code

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="tableAll">
  <tr>
     <th>Fruit name</th>
     <th>Color</th>
     <th>Notes</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Delicious</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

> here my Script

```
var $rows = $('#tableAll tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

you can also click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mggypoc0/2/) for code it in jsfiddle

Comment: Simply use the sibling selector `$('#tableAll tr + tr)` and it find only `tr` that comes after another `tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simply solution might be to look as of the second `tr` like in

```
var $rows = $('#tableAll tr:gt(0)');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers should definitely work in your specific case, but I would suggest making use of `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to work from cleaner HTML.

This way the code will also work if you have several headers, or even footers (if you put them into `<tfoot>`s).

```js
var $rows = $('#tableAll tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="tableAll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Fruit name</th>
       <th>Color</th>
       <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Delicious</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```